# plotly box and whisker plot with scatter plot with individualized colors

Tags: r, plotly

This is my first ever question so I apologize if it is a poorly worded question.
I was wondering whether anyone could help with overlaying adding a scatter plot to a box and whisker plot I have in r using plotly. The issue I am having is when I try to specify the colors of the scatter points it alters the box which i am trying to avoid.

[image: Box plot]

I have tried to specify the color with the name of the variable that I want to use but it effect the plot as seen below.

```r
f <- plot_ly(
  justq14, x = ~ description, y = ~high_speed_distance_min, type = "box", quartilemethod = "linear",
  boxpoints= 'all', color = ~player_name
)
```

[image: box and whisker with colors]

There is a legend to the right but due to it containing names I have omitted it.

Ideally it would look like the picture below or with the scatter to left. I found this on the internet

[image: Ideal End Product]